# Keras CNN stuck on epoch 1 for CIFAR10 datase

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to train a CNN which classifies the images from the CIFAR10 data base. Based on previous tasks with Keras the code should work like this

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from random import sample
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

cat_dict = {0: 'airplane',
            1: 'automobile',
            2: 'bird',
            3: 'cat',
            4: 'deer',
            5: 'dog',
            6: 'frog',
            7: 'horse',
            8: 'ship',
            9: 'truck'}

def assign_class(val):
    isclass = cat_dict[int(val)]
    return isclass

def show_imgs(X,Y):
    plt.figure(1, figsize=(20,20))
    k = 0
    for i in range(0,5):
        for j in range(0,5):
            plt.subplot2grid((5,5),(i,j))
            plt.imshow(X[k], cmap='gray')
            plt.title(assign_class(Y[k]))
            k = k+1
            plt.axis('off')
    # show the plot
    plt.show()
    
# Load data & split data between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

show_imgs(x_train, y_train)

print('Shape of training data:', x_train.shape)
print('Shape of test data:', x_test.shape)

# Normalization
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255.0
x_test /= 255.0

#One-hot encode
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

print(x_train.shape[0], 'training samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
print(y_train.shape[0], 'training label samples')
print(y_test.shape[0], 'test label samples')

E = 5   #epochs
B = 128 #batch size
n_classes = 10

cnn = keras.models.Sequential()

cnn.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (2,2), input_shape = (32,32,3), padding = 'valid', strides = (1,1) ))
cnn.add(keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
cnn.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))) 
cnn.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, input_shape = (3072,), activation='softmax'))

cnn.summary()

cnn.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

log = cnn.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = B, epochs = E, validation_data = (x_test, y_test), verbose = 1)
```

I would expect that the `.fit()` starts to fit the model but instead the only output I get is
"Epoch 1/5       " and nothing else (besides my computer starts to sound like an A747).

Comment: lower your batch size

Comment: I tried, but the same thing happens

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled a whole new environment and it worked with no problem